# Rails API builder with auto generated documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, api-versioning

I've been wondering is there any gem to generate API documentation for Rails app not only with versioning and **input** parameters but with documentation for **returned** parameters too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger does a pretty nice job of this. Best part is it's fully interactive as well. http://swagger.io

Comment: Thanks! Swagger looks pretty good for my needs